# how to add DTO source code file in services file in nest js app

Tags: typescript, schema, nestjs, dto

i have two files one is DTO,where i declare validations of methods and another file is services code where i write code of API. But i don't know how to inject DTO file class in services constructor().Here is the code of my DTO and services respectively.

service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { studentdto} from './student.dto';

@Injectable()
export class CrudService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('student') private readonly studentmodel:studentmodel<studentdto>
  ) { Object.assign(this, studentmodel)}
 async insert(name,rollno,section){
      const add_stu=new this.studentmodel({studentdto})
      return await add_stu.save()
 }
}
```

Here is the code of DTO file:

```
import {IsString, IsInt} from 'class-validator'
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
export class studentdto{
    @IsString()
    name:string

    @IsInt()
    rollno:number

    @IsString()
section:string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Update***

With mongoose you can do it like this:

***student.interface.ts***

```js
export interface Student {
  name: string;
  rollno: number;
  section: string;
};
```

***student.schema.ts***

```js
import { Schema } from 'mongoose'; 

export const StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  rollno: Number,
  section: String,
});
```

***crudService.service.ts***

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { studentdto} from './student.dto';
import { Student } from './student.interface.ts';
import { StudentSchema } from './student.schema.ts';


@Injectable()
export class CrudService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('STUDENT_MODEL') 
    private studentModel: Model<StudentSchema>
  ) {}

 async insert(studentDto: studentdto): Promise<Student> {
      const createdUser = new this.studentModel(studentDto);
      return createdUser.save()
 }
}
```

More information you can find [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/mongodb#mongodb-mongoose).

---

You can use your DTO in controller.

***Student.controller.ts***

```js
import { 
    Controller, Post, Body
} from "@nestjs/common";
import { CrudService } from './crud.service.ts';
import { studentdto} from './student.dto';

@Controller("student")
export class StudentController {
    constructor(
        private readonly crudService: CrudService
    ) {
        @Post("addStudent")
        addStudent(
            @Body() newStudent: studentdto
        ): studentdto {
            return this.crudService.insert(newStudent);
        }
    }
}
```

When you send a request, to `/student/addStudent` NestJS create an instance of `studentdto`.

Comment: so you mean there is no role of services if i add DTO directly to my controller. I also have one more query,what i'll write in services file because in controller i used crudServices to call methods of services files.

Comment: i want to add a new record of students in mongo db,can you please tell me what i write in insert function because thats the main issue of my question.I got confused in this portion of code.

Comment: @sahil, I did not see that you use the ```mongoose``` at first. Sorry. I updated an answer, hope it will help you.